# Backpack laravel Page Link empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

```
[id] => 1 
[name] => About us 
[type] => page_link 
[link] => 
[page_id] => 1 
[parent_id] => 
[lft] => 2 
[rgt] => 3 
[depth] => 1 
[created_at] => 2017-02-05 07:25:22 
[updated_at] => 2017-02-05 07:25:38 
[deleted_at] =>
```

When adding 'Type' as 'Page Link' and selecting page from dropdown. Page link is not being saved in database.

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. What do you want to achieve exactly? What code are you using to do so? What is the error message? Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Backpack\NewsCRUD, when a link to a page is stored, we don't store the actual link, as that might change it time. We store the `page_id`. So yes, `link` will be empty.

When you output your menu, for page links get the link when rendering. If you're using Backpack\PageManager, for example, instead of echoing `$menu_item->link`, echo `$menu_item->page->getPageLink()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works fine but there is confusion
1. How to render the mix of page, internal-links, external links using the above code.
2. How to parent before the page link as $menu_item->page->getPageLink() this also renders straight site-url/page-link